# IDEA убивает систему

Tags: intellij-idea

Не могу понять, почему IDEA вводить систему в ступор при попытке собрать проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Плагинов всего 2 стоит из того, что я доустанавливал...:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Процессор Core-I7 3770K. Да старый, но он не должен умирать...

Comment: Потому что сборка это процесс в принципе жорный, наверное? Я не знаю о каком конкретно проекте тут речь, но если рассуждать глобально, то этот жор даже не очень сильный

Comment: @andreymal может быть. Но Visual Studio мне никогда вот так не вешала машину.

Comment: На том же самом проекте с той же самой сборкой?

Comment: Ну Visual Studio пока не научился билдить проекты на Scala и проверить не могу=(

Comment: Ну значит причина скорее всего в Scala, которая сама по себе весьма жорная) Я не специалист в Scala, но, вероятно, есть смысл погуглить что-то про оптимизацию sbt или вроде того